# Is there a way to test if an APK is correctly zipaligned

Tags: android, apk, zipalign

Our customer uploaded the APK himself and has reported that the APK is not aligned. Which surprised me a lot and is rather embarrassing.

Before supplying a new APK I wonder if there is a way to test if an APK is correctly aligned.

There is of course `zipalign -c` — but this produces no output. Does no output mean success? Or is it in the return value? Or is there another tool which can do it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
zipalign -c -v 4 'path-to-apk'
```

-v flag gives you verbose output.

Comment: yes indeed. With `-v` there is either a *Verification successful* or a *Verification FAILED* at the end of the output. Perfect.